# Why can't I set up Plyer?

Tags: python, kivy

I am trying to install Plyer. But when I run setup.py I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/arden/Downloads/plyer-1.2.4/setup.py", line 28, in <module>
    changelog = fd.read()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/encodings/ascii.py", line 26, in decode
    return codecs.ascii_decode(input, self.errors)[0]
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 4636: ordinal not in range(128)
```

I don't know what's going on or if there's a better way to install it than just running it.

I use a Mac (OS 10.12) and Python 3.5 through IDLE.

Comment: No clue, both stable (`pip install plyer`) and master (`pip install https://github.com/kivy/plyer/zipball/master`) work ok for me on both py2 and py3.

Comment: Adding to KeyWeeUsr you can include it in requirements in buildozer.spec file if you are developing for ios or android.

Comment: I am developing for both (ideally...), I just installed buildozer, what do I type in the .spec to have it build plyer? Also, I'm testing it on my Mac. Will it still work?

Comment: Lurk around plyer examples.U need to put plyer in requirements as done [here](https://github.com/kivy/plyer/blob/master/examples/audio/buildozer.spec)

Comment: Now I'm having trouble figuring out how to use buildozer... :( Also if it helps pip install plyer installs it for python but not kivy. Am I doing it wrong?

Comment: Scratch that, I was doing pip install plyer instead of kivy -m pip install plyer. It works now. Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ways to use plyer with your projects :-

- Download [plyer](https://github.com/kivy/plyer) and set python path eg(export PYTHONPATH=~/code/plyer:$PYTHONPATH)
- Include plyer in your buildozer.spec file :)

Comment: This worked, but only once I realized you meant kivy -m pip install plyer instead of just pip install plyer.